# SOAP request is not correct while sending to SAP PI

Tags: wcf, soap, sap-pi, sap-xi

I'm consuming a SAP PI Web Service and some reason it's not working. I'm thinking due to incorrect SOAP XML below:

This is what SAP PI is expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:A_Request xmlns:ns0="http://domain.co.au/abc">
   <Root>
      <Element1>a</Element1>
      <Element1>a</Element1>
   </Recordset>
</ns0:A_Request>
```

This is what I'm sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<A_Request xmlns="http://domain.co.au/abc" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Root>
      <Element1>a</Element1>
      <Element1>a</Element1>
   </Recordset>
 </A_Request>
```

Is there any way (programatically or config) that can be done on client side in order to format the XML request as expected by Server?

Or, the it should be fixed in WSDL and client program (my program) will automatically generate the required XML?

Thank you heaps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not manually generate or format the XML sent to the server from the client side. If the server exposes a valid SOAP based service simply point the client to the WSDL and it will generate strongly typed classes that you can use to consume the service. If you are using .NET 3.0 or higher on the client it is recommended that you use the [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) (or Add Service Reference in VS) to generate those classes. If you are using an older version you could use [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (or Add Web Reference in VS).

Comment: Thanks Darin, I'm using .NET 4.0. Do you mean Server (SAP PI) should fix their WSDL with proper name spacing. It will then automatically picked up by client and generates a expected SOAP messsage?